# On showing that if $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu\in M_1(X)$ in weak* topology, then $\lim_n\int_X fd\mu_n=\int_X fd\mu$ for every Lipschitz function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $M_1(X)$ the set of Borel probability measures over $X$. Suppose that $\mu_n$ is a sequence in $M_1(X)$ such that $\mu_n$s converge to some $\mu\in M_1(X)$ in weak* topology, that is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X g(x)d\mu_n(x)=\int_X g(x)d\mu(x)$ for every bounded and continuous function $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to show that this implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f(x)d\mu_n(x)=\int_X f(x)d\mu(x)$ for every Lipschitz continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, but the fact that such an $f$ need not be bounded is giving me a headache. My idea was to take any such Lipschitz function $f$ and define

$$f_n(x) = f(x)1_{\{-n\leq f(x)\leq n\}} + n 1_{\{f(x) > n\}} - n1_{\{f(x) < -n\}}$$
Then $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ everywhere in $X$ as $n\to\infty$ and $f_n$ is a bounded and continuous function. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be fixed, but arbitrary. The prior construction reduces the problem of finding suitable $n$ such that

$$\left|\int_Xf(x)d\mu_n(x) - \int_Xf(x)d\mu(x)\right| < \varepsilon$$

to showing that

$$\left|\int_Xf(x) - f_n(x)d\mu_n(x) - \int_Xf(x) - f_n(x)d\mu(x)\right| \leq \int_X\left|f(x) - f_n(x)\right|d\mu_n(x) + \int_X\left|f(x) - f_n(x)\right|d\mu(x) < C\varepsilon$$

for some $C > 0$. At this point I would like to use any theorem which allows me to move a limit, limit superior or limit inferior inside the integrals of the above summand. But the superaddive property $\liminf_n(a_n + b_n)\geq \liminf_n (a_n) + \liminf_n(b_n)$ of the limit inferior prevents this approach (without additional information). And e.g. Fatou's lemma reverses the inequality if one uses limit superior. The Monotone convergence theorem is of no use for the sequence $|f(x) - f_n(x)|$ is not necessarily motonotically increasing.

(**Question:**) So, is there some unicorn result which allows me to move a limit inside the integrals or should I have constructed $f_n$ is a different manner or is there some alternative approach to conclude the claim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The statement of the OP does not hold in general. For example, consider the sequence of probability measures
  $$\mu_n=\left(1-{1\over n}\right)\delta_0+{1\over n}\delta_{n^2}$$
  on $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. Clearly $\mu_n\Longrightarrow\delta_0$ (convergence in distribution). Let $\phi(x)=x$. This is obviously a Lipshitz function; however
  $$\mu_n\phi=n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty\neq \delta_0\phi=0$$
- There is however an equivalence between weak convergence (convergence in distribution) and *quasi-convergence* along Lipschitz functions bounded from below:

> Theorem:  Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space.  For any net $\{\mu_\alpha:\alpha\in D\}\subset\mathcal{M}^+(S)$ and  $\mu\in \mathcal{M}^+(S)$, $\mu_\alpha\Rightarrow\mu$ if and only if
> $$\begin{align}
> \liminf_\alpha\int f\,d\mu_\alpha\geq \int f\,d\mu
> \end{align}$$
> for all $f\in L_b(S)$ where $L_b(S)$ is the collection of all Lipschitz functions that are bounded below.

Details can be found in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185673/121671) and references within.

- Under some uniform integrability conditions, weak convergence implies convergence over Lipschitz functions.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a separable metric space. suppose $(Y_n,Y:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence of random variables in $(X,d)$ such that $Y_n\Longrightarrow Y$. If for some $p\in (X,d)$, $(d(Y_n,p):n\in\mathbb{N})$ is uniform integrable, then
> $$\lim_n \int g(Y_n)\,dP\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int g(Y)\,dP$$
> for all Lipschitz function $g$.

Here is a sketch of the proof: Let $g\in \operatorname{Lip}(X,d)$ There is a constant $c>0$ such that
$$|g(Y_n)|\leq c d(Y_n,p)+|g(p)|$$
The uniform integrability of $(d(Y_n,p):n\in\mathbb{N})$ implies the uniform integrability of $(g(Y_n):n\in\mathbb{N})$
The conclusion follows from the following theorem:

> Theorem: If $\mu_n\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow}\mu$ and $Z$ is a (real valued) random variable, a sufficient condition for $E_{\mu_n}[Z]\rightarrow E_\mu[Z]$ is that
> $$\lim_{a\rightarrow\infty}\sup_n\int_{\{|x|>a\}}|x|\,\mu_n(dx)=0$$

This is equivalent to say that  a sequence of random variables $Z_n\sim \mu_n$, defined on a common domain $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ is uniformly integrable, then $Z_n$ converges in distribution to a random variable $Z\sim \mu$. This can be seen for instance in Billingsley, P. *Convergence in Probability Measures*, John Wiley & Sons, 1968, pp. 32.